# C incomplete type is not allowed error on list of strings

Tags: c

Hello I am new to C and I am trying to create a list of strings. But when I try to define the list uninitialized it gives me an error. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int size;
    char *sentence = "";
    char *allWords[]; //incomplete type is not allowed

    scanf("%d *[^\n]", &size);
    fgets(sentence, size + 1, stdin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: an array needs to be declared with a specific size, if you want dynamic allocation just use a double pointer and allocate the right size => `char **allWords;` like this

Comment: Tip: `char *sentence = "";` creates a **zero length buffer** that is completely useless for capturing data, not just because it's unable to hold any meaningful data, but because it's a read-only static string. `fgets` invokes undefined behaviour at this point. You probably mean `char sentence[size + 1]`.

Comment: `scanf("%d *[^\n]",` almost certainly does not do what you think it does.  I suspect you expect it to behave like `"%d%*[^\n]"` (But please read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @A.Vinuela: Re “an array needs to be declared with a specific size”: An array needs to be **defined** with a specific size (except for flexible array members). It does not need to be **declared** with a specific size. Declarations that do not define an array may use `[]`, as in `extern int a[]` or a parameter declaration `int a[]`.

Comment: @tadman: Re “a pointer to an array”: `char *allWords[];` declares `allWords` to be an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. If it were a pointer to an array, then the array size would not need to be specified; `char (*allWords[]);` is a valid definition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that you can just define a variable, BUFFER in this case for the lenght of the strings and ask for the size of the array list, then you can just make a for loop to store each value in a postion of the array list if you want with strcpy function (You cant use == to compare strings in C, that only work with chars because you're comparing ASCII value, for example 'a' == 97 is true).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER 50

int main(){
    int size;
    char sentence[BUFFER];

    printf("Introduce the size of the array list:");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    char allWords[size][BUFFER];
    fgets(sentence, size + 1, stdin);
    
    // Then you can insert the "sentence" in the array list with strcpy function included in <string.h>
    
    strcpy(allWords[Position], sentence); //Position not declared in this case, is just an example, you can use this in a loop with a variable iterating each position of the array list
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that starting from C11 VLAs are optional, that means a compiler is free to either accept or not the code `char allWords[size][BUFFER]`. Also this is error prone: what if the user enters a huge number? I would use dynamic allocation `char (*allWords)[BUFFER] = malloc(size*sizeof(*allWords));` Then at the end remember to `free(allWords);`